# How do you create asynchronous timers in OS X C code?

Tags: c, macos, system, distributed-computing

So this question is really "Why are time.h not the same on OS X and Linux?" but, I've made my peace with those differences.

To create timers on a 'Unix' system, I followed this tutorial http://www.helsinki.fi/atk/unix/dec_manuals/DOC_40D/APS33DTE/DOCU_007.HTM#timer-type-sec

which requires the use of `<sys/time.h>` and calling `timer_create()`, then setting up a signal handler for the signal type. This I know how to do. The question is, how is the same thing achieved on OS X?

The key thing to note is that these timers need to be realtime, that is, asynchronously queued and must use the `sa_sigaction` field of a `struct sigaction`, so that metadata associated with the timer alarm can be passed to the signal handler. This is described in more detail here http://www.helsinki.fi/atk/unix/dec_manuals/DOC_40D/APS33DTE/DOCU_006.HTM#sigevent-sec.

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into [`setitimer()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man2/setitimer.2.html)?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately this doesn't work as I need the timers to be asynchronous, and contain metadata about the event that fired them. This works in Linux using the `siginfo_t` data structure, which `timer_create()` allows me to set using the `sigevent` data structure as an input.