# Create C timer in macOS

Tags: ios, c, macos, timer, macos-sierra

I would like to know how to create a timer in macOS / iOS. In linux you can create it using timer_create() function of time.h class but in macOS / iOS this function don't exist.

Something like NSTimer (objective-c) but in C.

Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/194480/why-is-timer-t-defined-in-time-h-on-linux-but-not-os-x

Comment: You should be able to use `getitimer` and `setitimer`.

Comment: @JonnySchubert I read that link before post this question. Don't solve my question.

Comment: @jxh thanks, yes I know it and i'm trying to use it.

Comment: Have a look here: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/technotes/tn2169/_index.html

Comment: @jxh the problem with that functions is that i don't know how to specify the event that should be notified when the timer expires

Comment: @JonnySchubert thanks, but I need some method to be able to create a timer and define what event should trigger when timer expires... I'm searching for the alternative of timer_create method of linux time.h class.

Comment: If you look at the source of NSTimer.swift, you'll see it wraps CFRunLoopTimer, so then the question is: do you still have a CFRunLoop, or are you writing a bare C program?  If you don't have a run loop, then the answer to "how to specify the event" is simply: it's the function that you put after the "wait" call -- or you have to design your own run loop system, or build an equivalent with threads (like n3wb did below).  Just how much of the Mac infrastructure do you want to reinvent yourself?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you create asynchronous timers in OS X C code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10263856/608639)

Answer (score 8):

After updating the link for [Grand Central Dispatch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Central_Dispatch) timers ([Apple's page](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch)) on a previous answer, I created some example code for two timers.  It should be noted that this works on FreeBSD and MacOS, but not Linux (without GCD support).  The example creates two event timers, one that fires 0.2sec and one that fires 0.5sec over a total of 20 times.  There is a 1 second delay that exists before execution starts.  The `sleep()` functions are not used.

```
#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int i = 0;
dispatch_queue_t queue;
dispatch_source_t timer1;
dispatch_source_t timer2;


void sigtrap(int sig)
{
    dispatch_source_cancel(timer1);
    dispatch_source_cancel(timer2);
    printf("CTRL-C received, exiting program\n");
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void vector1(dispatch_source_t timer)
{
        printf("a: %d\n", i);
        i++;
        if (i >= 20) 
        {
            dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
        }   
}
void vector2(dispatch_source_t timer)
{
        printf("b: %d\n", i);
        i++;
        if (i >= 20)  //at 20 count cancel the 
        {
            dispatch_source_cancel(timer);
        }   
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]) {

    signal(SIGINT, &sigtrap);   //catch the cntl-c
    queue = dispatch_queue_create("timerQueue", 0);

    // Create dispatch timer source
    timer1 = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    timer2 = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, queue);
    
    // Set block for dispatch source when catched events
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer1, ^{vector1(timer1);});
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(timer2, ^{vector2(timer2);});

    // Set block for dispatch source when cancel source
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(timer1, ^{
        dispatch_release(timer1);
        dispatch_release(queue);
        printf("end\n");
        exit(0);
    });
    dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler(timer2, ^{
        dispatch_release(timer2);
        dispatch_release(queue);
        printf("end\n");
        exit(0);
    }); 

    dispatch_time_t start = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, NSEC_PER_SEC); // after 1 sec

    // Set timer
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer1, start, NSEC_PER_SEC / 5, 0);  // 0.2 sec
    dispatch_source_set_timer(timer2, start, NSEC_PER_SEC / 2, 0);  // 0.5 sec
    printf("start\n");    
    dispatch_resume(timer1);
    dispatch_resume(timer2);
    while(1)
    {
        ;;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use pthreads for macOS, with some combination of sleep and time

```
 typedef struct Timer {
        void (*fn)(void);
        bool (*timer_delegate)(pthread_t, unsigned int, unsigned int);
        unsigned int seconds;
 } Timer;

void* timer_run(void *t) {

    unsigned int start_time = time(NULL);
    while(1) {
        Timer tmr = *((Timer *) t);
        bool should_kill_thread = tmr.timer_delegate(pthread_self(), start_time, time(NULL));
        if (should_kill_thread) pthread_cancel(pthread_self());
        tmr.fn();

        sleep(tmr.seconds);
    }
}

bool should_kill_thread(pthread_t t, unsigned int start_time, unsigned int utime_new) {
    printf("the start time was %d and the new time is %d \n", start_time, utime_new);

    if (utime_new - start_time >= 9) {
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

void hello_world() {
    printf("%s\n", "Hello, World!");
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pthread_t t1;
    Timer args;
    args.fn = &hello_world;
    args.timer_delegate = should_kill_thread;
    args.seconds = 1; // call every 1 second

    int id = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, timer_run, &args);
    if (id) {
       printf("ERROR; return code from pthread_create() is %d\n", id);
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    pthread_join(t1, NULL); // blocks main thread
    printf("%s\n", "DONE"); // never reached until t1 is killed
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I need to use it in a timer wheel and I think that sleep have some limitations in my project.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on b_degnan's answer above (click that one), we had to (partially) support Linux code using timers, so we wrote a `time.h` that we could use directly.

```
#include <sys/stdtypes.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <mach/boolean.h>
#include <sys/errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <dispatch/dispatch.h>

#if !defined(MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12) || \
    (MAC_OS_X_VERSION_MIN_REQUIRED < MAC_OS_X_VERSION_10_12)
typedef int clockid_t;
#endif

struct itimerspec {
    struct timespec it_interval;    /* timer period */
    struct timespec it_value;       /* timer expiration */
};

struct sigevent;

/* If used a lot, queue should probably be outside of this struct */
struct macos_timer {
    dispatch_queue_t tim_queue;
    dispatch_source_t tim_timer;
    void (*tim_func)(union sigval);
    void *tim_arg;
};

typedef struct macos_timer *timer_t;

static inline void
_timer_cancel(void *arg)
{
    struct macos_timer *tim = (struct macos_timer *)arg;
    dispatch_release(tim->tim_timer);
    dispatch_release(tim->tim_queue);
    tim->tim_timer = NULL;
    tim->tim_queue = NULL;
    free(tim);
}

static inline void
_timer_handler(void *arg)
{
    struct macos_timer *tim = (struct macos_timer *)arg;
    union sigval sv;

    sv.sival_ptr = tim->tim_arg;

    if (tim->tim_func != NULL)
        tim->tim_func(sv);
}

static inline int
timer_create(clockid_t clockid, struct sigevent *sevp,
    timer_t *timerid)
{
    struct macos_timer *tim;

    *timerid = NULL;

    switch (clockid) {
        case CLOCK_REALTIME:

            /* What is implemented so far */
            if (sevp->sigev_notify != SIGEV_THREAD) {
                errno = ENOTSUP;
                return (-1);
            }

            tim = (struct macos_timer *)
                malloc(sizeof (struct macos_timer));
            if (tim == NULL) {
                errno = ENOMEM;
                return (-1);
            }

            tim->tim_queue =
                dispatch_queue_create("timerqueue",
                0);
            tim->tim_timer =
                dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER,
                0, 0, tim->tim_queue);

            tim->tim_func = sevp->sigev_notify_function;
            tim->tim_arg = sevp->sigev_value.sival_ptr;
            *timerid = tim;

            /* Opting to use pure C instead of Block versions */
            dispatch_set_context(tim->tim_timer, tim);
            dispatch_source_set_event_handler_f(tim->tim_timer,
                _timer_handler);
            dispatch_source_set_cancel_handler_f(tim->tim_timer,
                _timer_cancel);

            return (0);
        default:
            break;
    }

    errno = EINVAL;
    return (-1);
}

static inline int
timer_settime(timer_t tim, int flags,
    const struct itimerspec *its, struct itimerspec *remainvalue)
{
    if (tim != NULL) {

        /* Both zero, is disarm */
        if (its->it_value.tv_sec == 0 &&
            its->it_value.tv_nsec == 0) {
        /* There's a comment about suspend count in Apple docs */
            dispatch_suspend(tim->tim_timer);
            return (0);
        }

        dispatch_time_t start;
        start = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW,
            NSEC_PER_SEC * its->it_value.tv_sec +
            its->it_value.tv_nsec);
        dispatch_source_set_timer(tim->tim_timer, start,
            NSEC_PER_SEC * its->it_value.tv_sec +
            its->it_value.tv_nsec,
            0);
        dispatch_resume(tim->tim_timer);
    }
    return (0);
}

static inline int
timer_delete(timer_t tim)
{
    /* Calls _timer_cancel() */
    if (tim != NULL)
        dispatch_source_cancel(tim->tim_timer);

    return (0);
}
```

Or, as a gist:
https://gist.github.com/lundman/731d0d7d09eca072cd1224adb00d9b9e

I'd be happy to receive updates, if you enhance it further with more types. It can clearly be improved, but does just enough for our needs.

Went with straight C here, since it is a port of upstream source.